# FileSystemWatcher does not catch events for logging file before file is "evaluated" first via ls/dir

Tags: c#, winforms, logging, filesystems

I am trying to monitor a log file which is used by another application from within a WinForms program by using FileSystemWatcher (version with all debugging below):

```
        fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
            Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath),
            Filter = Path.GetFileName(filePath),
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes |
NotifyFilters.CreationTime |
NotifyFilters.FileName |
NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
NotifyFilters.Size |
NotifyFilters.Security
        };

        fileWatcher.Changed += FileWatcher_Changed;
        fileWatcher.Created += FileWatcher_Changed; // Handle Created event as well
        fileWatcher.Deleted += FileWatcher_Changed; // Handle Deleted event as well
```

The issue is that I get events only when I either open the file first in e.g. Notepad++, refresh the contents of a File Explorer or write ls in Git Bash.
Then the event is caught in my code and all is well.

Appreciate greatly any and all help in investigating what causes this and how to achieve the desired result